# How to connect a rating system w/ SQLite & PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to make a rating system (using SQLite, PHP, jQuery) to my website, but I don't know/understand how to connect my database (SQLite) to PHP. I'm totally new to this so it would be great if you could describe in details how I do it and maybe give a link to something helpful.

I've searched for an answer but couldn't really find one, since most of them is about MySql and not SQLite. As you know they have different syntax/methods and this makes me confused and harder to understand.

This is the database table that I want to connect:

```
id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
db_user TEXT
db_password TEXT
up INTEGER
down INTEGER
```

Extra: Do you think the table is good enough or do I need to add more fields? If yes, what should I add to make the rating system working good?

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail and only ask about one thing. It is quite impossible to comment on your table structure without knowing what this "rating system" does

Comment: Okay so basically my biggest problem is to connect the SQLite db and PHP in my system. Which commands/methods (dont really know what they are called) should I use? 

I have looked it up,  but dont understand what they mean since Im new to this. Some people say one thing and other another thing.